# How to use Query to add value in IQueryable?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, iqueryable

I want to add a value in IQueryable get from another IQueryable here is my code

```
var queryReturnRequest = query.Include(x => x.Assignment)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Asset).Select(x => new ReturnRequestDto
                {
                    AssetCode = x.Assignment.Asset.Code,
                    AssetName = x.Assignment.Asset.Name,
                    Id = x.Id,
                    ReturnDate = x.ReturnDate,
                    AssignedDate = x.Assignment.AssignedDate,
                    State = x.State,
                    UserRequestId = x.UserRequestId,
                    UserAcceptId = x.UserAcceptId,
                    RequestedBy = userList.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == x.UserRequestId) != null ? userList.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == x.UserRequestId).UserName : "",
                    AcceptedBy = userList.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == x.UserAcceptId) != null ? userList.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == x.UserAcceptId).UserName : "",
                });
```

But it was crashed and return error 500, I found out that was because of userList.FirstOrDefault but when I console.log() it just work fine. So what wrong with it and is there another way to add it in IQueryable ?

I tried to user for loop to add IQueryable but it just return to null after get our of loop.

Comment: Try to avoid the ternary operator. What about `.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == x.UserRequestId)?.UserName ?? ""`

Comment: I have tried .FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == x.UserRequestId)?.UserName ?? "" but it not allow to do that

Comment: @tinySharkk you should add the exception that is causing the 500 error to your question otherwise every answer will just be guessing what is wrong. Also you shoud mention wich version of EF you are using

Answer (score 1):

Try rewrite query in the following way. Also note that `Select` discards `Include`s, so avoid them in such case.

```cs
var queryReturnRequest = query
    .Select(x => new ReturnRequestDto
    {
        AssetCode = x.Assignment.Asset.Code,
        AssetName = x.Assignment.Asset.Name,
        Id = x.Id,
        ReturnDate = x.ReturnDate,
        AssignedDate = x.Assignment.AssignedDate,
        State = x.State,
        UserRequestId = x.UserRequestId,
        UserAcceptId = x.UserAcceptId,
        RequestedBy = userList.Where(u => u.Id == x.UserRequestId).Select(x => x.UserName).FirstOrDefault() ?? "",
        AcceptedBy = userList.Where(u => u.Id == x.UserAcceptId).Select(x => x.UserName).FirstOrDefault() ?? "",
    });
```